# Webpack css-loader: how to import file to a specific place in the code?

Tags: css, angular, webpack, less, css-loader

In order to use Angular style encapsulation for specific parts of the app I want to load with css-loader the styles from another file to another place with preserving the structure of the top-level file. In my `.less` file I have a code like this:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
    @import '~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
    @import '~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css';
}
```

The point here is to use less syntax to add `:host ::ng-deep` prefix to every rule in the imported files. However the structure is not preserved, so it works as if the files were imported outside of the outer selector. eventually, after using `require(css-loader!./myfile.less).toString()` it works like this:

```
@import '~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
@import '~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css';

:host ::ng-deep {
}
```

With imports replaced by their contents.

The current stack of loaders are `css-loader`, `postcss-loader` and `less-loader`.

Is there a way to keep the structure with the current loaders? If not, in your opinion, what is the best way of solving this problem?